# Add custom text as a label in front of RSS feed icon

Tags: 8, feeds

I want to change the label from "Subscribe to News" to "Subscribe to News Feed" displayed with RSS icon in drupal8. Also I need to open a popup window on clicking icon.

Attaching the screenshot:

[image]

Any help to figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [feed-icon.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21feed-icon.html.twig/8.2.x)

you need copy `feed-icon.html.twig` in `core/modules/system/templates/feed-icon.html.twig` to `themes/yourtheme/templates/feed-icon.html.twig`

in file `themes/yourtheme/templates/feed-icon.html.twig`

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation for a feed icon.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - url: An internal system path or a fully qualified external URL of the feed.
 * - attributes: Remaining HTML attributes for the feed link.
 *   - title: A descriptive title of the feed link.
 *   - class: HTML classes to be applied to the feed link.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
<a href="{{ url }}"{{ attributes.addClass('feed-icon') }}>
  {{ 'Subscribe to News Feed'}}
</a>
```

Comment: @PriyaAgarwal Please +1 to my answer :)

Comment: The core template uses the t filter to make the text translatable, so it would be better to include that here as well.

Comment: What about if I want that twig to be different for each specific view? How should I rename it? Please